# Checking the status of a device ,if the device is connected to a network

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have an application running on my desktop which uses TCP sockets to establish connection with another card reader . a rough description of how the devices are connected is as shown below

Desktop - (hosting the application) connected to an external connector | card reader also connected to the same connector 
Each time application wants to connect to  the card reader it establishes a TCP/IP socket connection and sends data to a particular port.

how can a utility in c#,be written which keeps track of the card reader and intimates my application as soon the card reader is disconnected or out of network

Comment: Rough sketch is missing. Much disappointment.

Comment: I second John. I really am disappointed.

Comment: how to add a rough sketch , i was hoping someone can help.Thats why i just gave a rough explanation how the connection looks like in the second para